# EnsureDispatch error when using cx_freeze for making exe

Tags: python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze, win32com

I am working with Python 3.4 on Windows 7. My setup file is as follows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable, sys

exe=Executable(
 script="XYZ.py",
 base="Win32Gui",

 )
includefiles=[]
includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
setup(

 version = "1.0",
 description = "XYZ",
 author = "MAX",
 name = "AT",
 options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
 executables = [exe]
 )


from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os, difflib

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "XYZ.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
    )
```

When the obtained exe is run, an error pops up saying:

```
...
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\CLSIDToClass.py", line 46, in GetClass
    return mapCLSIDToClass[clsid]
KeyError: '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
```

I just can't figure out the problem here. Help, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use static proxy for your `win32com.client` code?

Comment: @Fenikso i didnt get it....what is static proxy....?
I am simply reading some contents from word documents and for that i am using import win32com.client in my script XYZ.py...

Comment: If you do not know what it is, you are probably using `EnsureDispatch`. It generates static proxy automatically. It has some benefits, but it will probably break cx_freeze. Try using `Dispatch` instead. See http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/generate-a-static-com-proxy.html .

Comment: Tried Dispatch also....throws an error...'module' object has no attribute 'Dispatch'...I used py2exe as well...but the same error again....thnks

Comment: Did you try `win32com.client.Dispatch` or `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch`?

Comment: I tried win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch(Word.Application) and it works.....so i have a standalone exe....thanks a ton Fenikso....genius....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using static proxy which is generated on your disk and which has the compiled executable trouble finding. If you do not know what the static proxy is, you are probably using `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch` which generates static proxy automatically.

The easiest way to fix the problem is to use dynamic proxy by using `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch`. Static proxy has some benefits, but there is a high possibility that you do not need it.

You can find more information about static and dynamic proxies to COM objects here: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/generate-a-static-com-proxy.html

Comment: I was hoping that static proxy will be generated in a "freezed" application too. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I've just figured out that the problem with `EnsureDispatch` is within `gencache` module, it assumes to be in read-only mode when an executable is built with `cx_freeze`.

The following lines allow cache to be built inside `AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\#.#\` directory in Windows 7 x64:

```
from win32com.client import gencache
if gencache.is_readonly:
    gencache.is_readonly = False
    gencache.Rebuild() #create gen_py folder if needed
```

References:

- [py2exe/pyinstaller and DispatchWithEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698169/1119602) answer
- [py2exe.org: UsingEnsureDispatch](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/UsingEnsureDispatch)

P. S. Performance is much better with static dispatch